# My code does not check the indexes of all of the arrays (lottery program)

Tags: c#

I am making a lottery program, it's basic and only view-able via console at the moment.

The program executes the following:

1. User enters 6 numbers ranging from 1 - 46.
2. Program generates 6 random numbers with the same range.
3. Program compares indexes to see which numbers the user managed to match with the program.
4. Program displays the same numbers which the user got right.

But, currently, there is a bug in my code and I am not sure how to proceed.

For example, my inputs are: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6

The program generated 6 numbers and I've managed to hit number 2 and 6.
But, the program only displayed number 2.
This means that my code is not comparing each and every index, and I am not sure why.

The user array is `lucky`, and the program generated array is `numbers`.

```
Console.WriteLine("The winning numbers are: , " );

int[] winning = new int[6];
int w = 0;
var x = 0;
var j = 0;
Console.WriteLine("The winning numbers are: , " );

int[] winning = new int[6];
int w = 0;
var x = 0;
var j = 0;
while (x< 6)
{    
   if (lucky[j] == numbers[x])
   {
       winning[w] = numbers[x];
       Console.WriteLine(winning[w]);
       w++;
   }
   j++;

   if (j == 5)
   {
       x++;
       j = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: since you're iterating over an array, why don't you use for loops?

Comment: You're increasing j and not x (you're doing it inside the last if). try to add `x++` under `j++`

Comment: While trying to use the Intersect and just trying to display the matches I am getting this:  The winning numbers are: , System.Linq.Enumerable+<IntersectIterator>d__70`1[System.Int32]  ( that's just after trying to do a simple Console.WriteLine(Matches), please excuse my ignorance , I did not yet learn this topic..

Comment: @ShlomiU Please have a look at my answer for one change you need in your current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to do all that looping these days. LINQ's [Intersect function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) makes it a single function call:

```
var Matches = lucky.Intersect(numbers);
```

will return all matching numbers from the two lists in `Matches`.

A looping equivalent might look like this (writing off the top of my head):

```
List<int> winning = new List<int>();
for(int i=0; i<numbers.Length; i++)
{
  if(numbers.Contains(lucky[i])
    winning.Add(lucky[i]);
}
```

To display it on console, use a simple loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<winning.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(winning[i]);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is homework and OP is expected to work out the algorithm. Do you have a plan B?

Comment: That may be true, but OP didn't mention looping as a requirement.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, while you are correct; answer are not only for op but for the future. If there is a shorter path it must be an answer.

Comment: There are no requirements , this is my project actually and I do get graded on it , also.. I did not yet learn the intersect function yet, so I don't really know how to implement it .

Comment: Agreed, but maybe (and if) you could write that from the top of your head, for bonus points ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Thanks. Added loop version. Let's see how many more that can accumulate. :)

Comment: Source reference of Intersect iterator: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f4105a494115b366

Comment: @dotNET, ho for link like this use msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8 . It has exemple and shit. Previous link is for people looking for how intersect work compare to handmade algo

Comment: @xdtTransform: Yep, Realized that immediately after inserting that link. I'll update again.

Comment: While trying to use the Intersect and just trying to display the matches I am getting this: The winning numbers are: , System.Linq.Enumerable+<IntersectIterator>d__70`1[System.Int32] ( that's just after trying to do a simple Console.WriteLine(Matches), please excuse my ignorance , I did not yet learn this topic..

Comment: @ShlomiU: Of course. winning is an `IEnumerable`. Think of it like an array or collection, so you have to use a loop to display it on the console.

Comment: @ShlomiU: Added code for looping through `winning` and printing them on screen.

Comment: Thank you , and thanks to everyone for helping me , I got everything straightened out now.

Answer (score 2):

Since you run over an array, the standard procedure would be to use a for loop.
Here are three solutions that solve the problem.
Each one is complete and can be tested on https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Linq: Use the [`Intersects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect) method to find the common items between two `IEnumerables`.

```
using System;

using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // at this point unique numbers have been generated and inputted
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] guesses = { 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        List<int> matches = new List<int>(numbers.Intersect(guesses));
        foreach (int n in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hit: " + n.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Using a single `for` loop and checking with the [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-contains) method (Array implements the IList interface) if the other array contains the number at the current index. You could also use a `foreach` loop, since you don't care about the indexes.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // at this point unique numbers have been generated and inputted
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] guesses = { 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        List<int> matches = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < guesses.Length; i++)
        {
            if (numbers.Contains(guesses[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hit: " + guesses[i].ToString());
                matches.Add(guesses[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of you could use a nested `for` loops, one for each array, to check each number from one array against every number of the other one.
Again you could use `foreach` loops.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // at this point unique numbers have been generated and inputted
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] guesses = { 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        List<int> matches = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < guesses.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (guesses[i] == numbers[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hit: " + guesses[i].ToString());
                    matches.Add(guesses[i]);
                    break; // optional, we found the number and can leave the loop. Not optional if your lottery allows numbers to happen more than once.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for the question why your code isn't working:
You set `j = 0` when `j == 5` just after `j++`, meaning you set `j` to 0 after checking index 4. While I do not want to encourage such unorthodox styles you could fix it by comparing `j == 6`. Again, this approach makes your code unreadable, please use one of the other solutions.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // at this point unique numbers have been generated and inputted
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] guesses = { 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        int[] winning = new int[6];
        int w = 0;
        var x = 0;
        var j = 0;
        while (x < 6)
        {
            if (guesses[j] == numbers[x])
            {
                winning[w] = numbers[x];
                Console.WriteLine(winning[w]);
                w++;
            }
            j++;
            if (j == 6)
            {
                x++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is that finding common items from two arrays.

```
var ar1 = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6}; 
var ar2 = new int[] {2,3,4,6,7,8}; 
var common = ar1.Intersect(ar2);
```

In your case

```
var common = lucky.Intersect(numbers);
```

Using loops

```
// Array size is fixed here.
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // OR i < lucky.Length (guessing numbers)
{
    if (numbers.Contains(lucky[i]))
    {
        // NUMBERS DETECTED
    }
}
```

Comment: that loop solution will not work if the indexes of same numbers don't match. example { 1, 2, 3 } will not match 3 for { 3, 4 ,5}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the checking of last index(5 in this case). It is *never* happening!

`//say j = 4`

`lucky[4] == numbers[x]`  //false/true, whatever value of x is

You increment j
`//j is now 5`

`if(j==5)`

Yes and then you are resetting it to 0.
last index which is 5 in this case will never be checked in the next iteration

> Solution- 
>   `if(j == 6)`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building 2 methods that basically do what everyone here has told me.
Since I did not yet learn LinQ I couldn't understand , I didn't learn LIST as well so I couldn't use it as well.

My functions are like this:

First function: checks the indexes of a specified array
code:

```
static bool DoesExists(int[] a, int Value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Value == a[i])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

second function checks how many repeated elements are in 2 arrays
code:

```
static int CountCorrect(int[] pc, int[] user)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < user.Length; i++)
            {
                if (DoesExists(pc, user[i]))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }
```

when using these 2 in conjunction , it solves my problem.
thanks to everyone for taking the time to give me good ideas.